# Game maker - Image index will not change

Tags: game-maker

I have two items, Object_Player and Object_Weapon.
Object_Player's sprite can be three different sprites and Object_Weapon's sprite index should vary depending on Object_Player's sprite.
For example, if Object_Player is set to the sprite Sprite_Hero1, the sprite index for Object_Weapon should be the first image in the sprite Sprite_Weapon.  If Object_Player is set to the sprite Sprite_Hero2, the sprite index for Object_Weapon should be the second image in the sprite Sprite_Weapon.

This is the code which changes the index for Object_Weapon.  It is in a create block for the Object_Weapon

```
if (Object_Player.image_index = Sprite_Hero1) sprite_index = 0
if (Object_Player.image_index = Sprite_Hero2) sprite_index = 1
if (Object_Player.image_index = Sprite_Hero3) sprite_index = 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're confused `sprite_index` and `image_index`. Try change:

```
if (Object_Player.sprite_index = Sprite_Hero1) image_index = 0
if (Object_Player.sprite_index = Sprite_Hero2) image_index = 1
if (Object_Player.sprite_index = Sprite_Hero3) image_index = 2
```